# How to sync Airship legend component data with CARTO VL legend data

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-vl, airship

I am trying to sync Airship category legend data as a VueJS component but it looks like the data property is not digesting the values properly:

```
<legend orientation="vertical" data="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"></legend>
```

This is my pseudo-code. I have a legend VueJS component:

```
Vue.component('Legend', {
    'template': 
    `
    <as-legend-category
        ref="widget"
        :bind="$attrs"
    >
    </as-legend-category>
    `,
    props: {
        data:{ type: Array }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            widget: null,
            isLoading: true
        }
    },
    watch: {
        data: function(newValue){
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.widget.data = newValue;
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.widget = this.$refs.widget
        const widget = this.widget;
    }
});
```

This is how I load it on my HTML:

```
<legend orientation="vertical" :data="computedLegendData"></legend>
```

I got the legend data from CARTO VL when the layer is updated:

```
layer.on('updated' , function () {
  vm.legendData = layer.viz.color.getLegendData().data;
});
```

And this is my `vue-config.js`:

```
// ignore airship tags
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [/as-\w+/];

const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        legendData: [],
        ...
    },
    computed: {
        computedLegendData: function() {
            const data = [];
            for (let index = 0; index < this.legendData.length; index++) {
                const element = this.legendData[index];
                data.push({
                    color: this.rgbToHex(element['value']),
                    label: element['key'],
                    type: 'point',
                    width: 16
                })
            }
            return data;
        },
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        rgbToHex: function (color) {
            return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (color.r << 16) + (color.g << 8) + color.b).toString(16).slice(1);
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

As you have noticed I have to calculated a new legend data object because what CARTO returns is not enough and colors need to be transformed to hex values.

You can check the code [here](https://github.com/ramiroaznar/carto-vl-as-template/tree/legends).